# wso2 ESB: server configuration CRITICAL

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

**My Scenario:** I have server_1 (192.168.10.1) with wso2-ESB and server_2 (192.168.10.2) with Glassfish-v3 + web services.

**Problem**: I am trying to create a proxy in ESB using the java Web Services, but the created proxy does not respond properly. The log says: `Unable to sendViaPost` for http or https does not change the result.

I think I should configure the `axis2.xml` but I am having trouble, and don't know what to do. What is the configuration for my scenario? Please help me!

**EDIT**: To be clear, I can directly consume the WebService in the Glassfish server, it works normal, both port and url are accessible. Only when I create a "**Pass through Proxy**" in the ESB, it does not work. I don't think is matter of Proxy configuration...I never had problems while deployed locally, problems started once I have uploaded the ESB to a remote server.

I really would need someone to point me what is the correct procedure when installing the ESB on a remote host: configuration of **axis2.xml** and **carbon.xml**, **ports**, **transport receivers** etc... P.S. I had a look at the official (wso2 esb and carbon) guides with no luck, but I am missing something...

**Endpoint of Java Web Service**: `http://192.168.10.2:8080/HelloWorld/Hello?wsdl`

**ESB Proxy Enpoint**: `http://192.168.10.1:8280/services/HelloProxy`

The following is my **axis2.xml** configuration, please check it:

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">192.168.10.1</parameter>
        <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https//192.168.10.1:8280</parameter>
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
    </transportReceiver>

    <!-- the non blocking https transport based on HttpCore + SSL-NIO extensions -->
    <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener">
        <parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>
        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="bind-address" locked="false">192.168.10.1</parameter>
        <parameter name="WSDLEPRPrefix" locked="false">https://192.168.10.1:8243</parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="priorityConfigFile" locked="false">location of priority configuration file</parameter>-->
        <parameter name="httpGetProcessor" locked="false">org.wso2.carbon.transport.nhttp.api.NHttpGetProcessor</parameter>
        <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
                <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="SSLVerifyClient">require</parameter>
            supports optional|require or defaults to none -->
    </transportReceiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unable to sendViaPost", happens when the endpoint is not reachable. from where are you trying to access the proxy. what is the URL of the proxy. first try if you can access the host and the port of that URL.

Regards,
/Nuwan

Comment: I can access both url an port. I need help with the axis2 configuration.

Answer (score 1):

lack of information.

what is your proxy config?
specify the full error.

try to set org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.wire logger to trace.
this will log all http actifivies and probably you could understand the reason of the error.

Comment: I will try to enable the logger, where do I find it by the way? The proxy configuration is a normal "Pass through proxy", I don't think it matters, since my previous local deployment was working normally. I need help with setting up a remote host configuration. (Please check the EDIT*)